# Как посчитать количество бит, установленных в 0 в коде ASCII для английских букв?

Tags: pascal

Имеется массив (ch) английских букв 'A-Z' 'a-z'. Надо посчитать количество бит, установленных в 0 в коде ASCII для этих букв. Получилось следущее:

```
  for k := 0 to 8 * sizeof(char) do
  begin
     if ch[k] and (1 shl k) = 0 then
     kbit := kbit + 1;
  end;
```

Что здесь нужно сделать, чтобы корректно побитово умножить символ и число?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция на языке паскаль (его изучение должен рассматривать комитет по защите прав человека)

```
function nzerobits (ch: array of char):integer;
var i, ones, ch1: integer;
begin
    (* количество единичек *)
    ones := 0;
    for i:=low(ch) to high(ch) do 
    begin
        ch1 := integer(ch[i]);
        while(ch1 <> 0) do
        begin
            ch1 := ch1 and (ch1 - 1);
            inc(ones);
        end;
    end;
    (* количество нулей *)
    nzerobits := (high(ch) - low(ch) + 1) * 8 - ones
end;
```

Дополнение: [[@Vahan Av](/users/877/vahan-av)](/users/877/vahan-av) посоветовал заменить сишную конструкцию ch1 := integer(ch[i]) на изначально паскалевскую ch1 := ord(ch[i]); Кому надо, тот поменяет.

Comment: И еще комитет про правам чайников;

Замените хотябы ch1 := integer(ch[i]); на ch1 := ord(ch[i]);

Comment: Был неудобный, но стройный язык pascal, а потом стал более удобный, но менее стройный трупный паскаль (далее -- тр.пас. с объедками). Снявши голову, по волосам не плачут. Но вот совет, как изобразить заголовок функции на виртовском паскале мне было бы интересно увидеть. Это я про `ch: array of char`. Вроде раньше так нельзя было...

Answer (score 1):

Для 1-ой буквы:

```
var
  c:char;
  count,i,temp:integer;

begin
  c:='A';
  count := 0;
  temp := ord(c);
  for i:=0 to 7 do
    if temp and (1 shl i) = 0 then
        inc(count);
  writeln(count);
end.
```

Дальше думаю не сложно прогнать так весь массив.